# What will happen to the event if spring SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor exceeds the concurrencyLimit?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have event listener which is annotated @async and use SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor for generate new thread with set concurrencyLimit. What happen if in the same time I will publish event exceeds concurrencyLimit? It will be ignore or just will be wait wait for free executor? If it wait, will it block main thread which published the event?

Unfortunate I'm not able to simulate this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `execute()` method, before creating the new thread, uses class [`ConcurrencyThrottleSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ConcurrencyThrottleSupport.html) to handle the concurrency limit; this class uses wait/notify logic to block the calling thread if the limit has been reached.  Before blocking the caller this class logs a debug message.

As its name suggests, this executor is quite simple.  A [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) is a better choice: it reuses threads and let you choose what to do when you reach the limit by definining a [`RejectedExecutionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html).

Comment: Brilant answer. I just have read that this SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor is good option for async handle events. I see now not in my case. Thank you for answer , I'm impressed .